# Angular .htaccess for root and subdirectory

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess

I am using multiple angular projects on single server,
This is my folder structure of my projects

```
Root: Project-1
Root/test : Project2
Root/test/new : project3
```

Here is the htaccess code, that I am using. but subdirectory projects not working some times

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

The issue is, when I am trying to access the second project using this url, `www.domain.com/test`, its redirecting to `root` folder, that is `project1` . I think it's checking project1 routing, when iIaccess project2

How can I fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code in your question, could you please do mention what is the problem you are facing? Also please do post samples of urls too which will help us to understand your question more clearly, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The issue is, when i'm trying to access the second project using this url, www.domain.com/test, its redirecting to root folder, that is project1. i think it's checking project1 routing, when i access project2.

Comment: have any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar project structure and the below **.htaccess** works for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

See if it works.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, unfortunately it's not working, still it's redirecting to root folder.

Comment: @SadiqueHere Does your projects contain any guards for routing? Like auth or something else?

Comment: And one more thing. Try hash location strategy on projects other than root.

Comment: i checked guardless routes, it's also not working.

Comment: All my non-root projects have hash location so that i can route to a specific component using **window.location.href**.

Answer (score 0):

Look my friend. What you want to do is easily solved.

There are 2 important places to make your app start url clear to Angular:

**1 - In the index.html file**

**2 - In the .htaccess file on the server**

The changes that you must make for the "Project2" are the following.

**1 - You look within your code in index.html of your Angular app for the following line of code:**

```
<base href = "/" />
```

You will modify it by putting the following

```
<base href = "/test/" />
```

**2 - You create the .htacces file in the root of the Root/test directory with the following content:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond% {HTTPS}! = On
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Https: //% {HTTP_HOST}% {REQUEST_URI} [L, R = 301, NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"


# If a path or directory request exists, go to it as is

RewriteCond% {DOCUMENT_ROOT}% {REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond% {DOCUMENT_ROOT}% {REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the source of the request does not exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Note that in the last line `RewriteRule ^ /index.html` and change it to your path to the index.html file of your compilation, leaving it as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^ /test/index.html
```

That is all.
Now you will do the same procedure for Project3 and you will see how everything works perfectly. Ej:
In index.html `<base href = "/test/new/" />`
and in .htaccess `RewriteRule ^ /test/new/index.html`